# golang gocql failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:9042 not enough bytes to read header require 9 got: 8

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I get this error trying to compile:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "log"
import "github.com/gocql/gocql"
var (
    name, sex string
    age int
)
func main() {
    // connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
    cluster.Keyspace = "dbaccess"
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 4
    if err := session.Query("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name='doug'").Scan(&name, &age); 
    err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(name, age)
}
```

I added the line

```
cluster.ProtoVersion = 4
```

After reading about it [here](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/538) but I'm too new to understand if that's my issue, or I did something wrong elsewhere. Do I have to wait for an update to gocql that fixes this, or what should I do?

Comment: Just a wild guess, look likes protocol version mismatch, what is your Cassandra version ?

Comment: 3.1.1. I just switched this line `cluster.ProtoVersion = 3` as a test to reflect 3.x, but now it says `no response received from cassandra within timeout period`

Comment: Starting from Cassandra 3.x.x, the protocol version should be 4 normally. If you're having issue with the go driver using protocol v4, raise an issue at their github. I'm using the Java driver and it works with protocol v4

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I sorted out with @Zariel on the github issue #538 thread. You have to put the ProtoVersion = 4 up by the first gocql stuff like:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "log"
import "github.com/gocql/gocql"

var (
    name, sex, age string
)

func main() {
    // connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 4
    cluster.Keyspace = "dbaccess"
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    if err := session.Query("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name='doug'").Scan(&name, &age); 
    err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(name, age)
}
```

Hope that helps someone else :)